# Is there such commands to merge multiple files in shell?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix, sed

For example, there're 5 numbers => [1,2,3,4,5] and 3 groups

File1(Group1):

```
1
3
5
```

File2(Group2):

```
3
4
```

File3(Group3):

```
1
5
```

Output (column1: whether in Group1, column2: whether in Group2, column3: whether in Group3 [NA means not..]):

```
1 NA 1
3 3 NA
NA 4 NA
5 NA 5
```

Or something like this (+ means in, - means not):

```
1 + - +
3 + + -
4 - + -
5 + - +
```

I tried `join` and `merge`, but looks like both of them doesn't work well for **multiple** files.. (for example, 8 files)

Comment: i'm probably blind, but I don't see the merging logic you're after. Can you elaborate as to what your merge result is based on?

Comment: @favoretti NA in columnN means there's no such item for fileN

Comment: @sputnick NA is placeholder means not available..

Comment: The logic is pretty unclear. The first line should be "1 3 1 " based on your question

Comment: Instead of showing strange output without explaining the logic, **explain in English what you expect**

Comment: Eureka I see the pattern!  Column 1 is File1 (top to bottom): 1,3,NA,5 and the file contains 1,3,5 but not a value for the "4" row so a NA is entered.  This is going to be incredibly hard to do no matter what tool you use.  You are wanting to append a file vertically in columns with unknown padding values using a built-in shell tool. Good luck with that.  Also, what happened to the row for "2"?

Comment: @Firegun Are your numbers 1-5 of any significance here? You are only using numbers which occur in your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say there's numbers 1-5, but this is, as far as I can see, irrelevant for the output you want. You only use numbers found in your files in the output. This code will do what you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @hashes;
my %seen;
local $/;   # read entire file at once
while (<>) {
    my @nums = split;                          # split file into elements
    $seen{$_}++ for @nums;                     # dedupe elements
    push @hashes, { map { $_ => $_ } @nums };  # map into hash
}

my @all = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %seen;       # sort deduped elements
# my @all = 1 .. 5;                            # OR: provide hard-coded list

for my $num (@all) {                           # for all unique numbers
    my @fields;
    for my $href (@hashes) {                   # check each hash
        push @fields, $href->{$num} // "NA";   # enter "NA" if not found
    }
    say join "\t", @fields;                    # print the fields
}
```

You may replace the sorted deduped list in `@all` with just `my @all = 1 .. 5` or any other valid list. It will then add lines for those numbers and print out extra "NA" fields for the missing values.

You should also be aware that this relies on the fact that your file contents are numbers, but only as far as it comes to the sorting of the `@all` array, so if you replace it with your own list, or your own sorting routine, you can use any value.

This script will take an arbitrary number of files and process them. For example:

```
$ perl script.pl f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt
1       NA      1
3       3       NA
NA      4       NA
5       NA      5
```

Credit to [Brent Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353186/brent-stewart) for figuring out what the OP meant.

Answer (score 0):

For two files, you can easily use `join` as shown below (assuming `file1` and `file2` are sorted):

```
$ join -e NA -o 1.1,2.1 -a 1 -a 2  file1 file2
1 NA
3 3
NA 4
5 NA
```

It gets more complicated if you have more than two files though.

Here is a brute force `grep` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=(file1 file2 file3)
sort -nu "${files[@]}" | while read line; do
    for f in "${files[@]}"; do   
         if grep -qFx "$line" "$f"; then
             printf "${line}\t"
         else
             printf "NA\t"
         fi
    done
    printf "\n"
done
```

Output:

```
1       NA      1
3       3       NA
NA      4       NA
5       NA      5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @lines;
my $filecount = 0;

# parse
for my $filename (@ARGV){
  open my $fh, '<', $filename;
  while( my $line = <$fh> ){
    chomp($line);
    next unless length $line;
    $lines[$line][$filecount]++;
  }
  close $fh;
}continue{
  $filecount++;
}

# print
for my $linenum ( 1..$#lines ){
  my $line = $lines[$linenum];
  next unless $line;

  print ' ' x (5-length $linenum), $linenum, ' ';

  for my $elem( @$line ){
    print $elem ? 'X' : ' '
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

```
    1 X X
    3 XX
    4  X
    5 X X
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input files are monotonically increasing and just consist of a single integer on each line as your input samples suggest, you could simply pre-process the input files and use paste:

```
for i in file{1,2,3}; do  # List input files
  awk '{ a += 1; while( $1 > a ) { print "NA"; a += 1 }} 1' $i > $i.out
done
paste file{1,2,3}.out
```

This leaves the trailing entries in some columns empty.  Fixing that is left as an exercise for the reader.